# Add tablestyle to default gallery for anything opened in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to add my own tablestyles to excel 2010 via vba for any workbook I create or open. I can get it to work with an XLA file in the startup for new sheets that open when Excel starts, but I can't make the gallery contain my style for any other sheet. Driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

how does you code is executed within your XLA ? i mean, from which event ?

If your XLA is only *loaded by default* (i.e. in Excel default folder *C:\Program Files...*), then it will be loaded **only for new Workbooks** because Excel relies on the default template **MyWorkbook** (and loads the defaults XLA).

Comment: It is loaded by default. How do I add the table style to Excel in general (the default template)?

Comment: i think you can kind of "install" it with `Tools` and then `Addins`

Comment: I've never had that work before. I'd like worksheets I've already saved to see the interface and table styles in my default template.

Comment: they will if you check them in `Tools` > `Addins`. You may have to restart Excel though